# Can I to know if ipad was rebooted?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, clock

I am developing an application that must work online and also offline. This application should sync informations with our server. For this, we need that the device utilize the server clock.
I found a lot of information, and I get the following idea:

1. When the user logins online I will force him to get the server clock time. In this moment he obrigatory must have internet connection, so it is ok.
2. When I get the clock server time, I get the systemUptime information that says the interval that the device is turned on, and I store it. I can get systemUptime like this:

   ```
   [NSProcessInfo processInfo].systemUptime
   ```
3. When the user to create a new local file, I will know the current interval based on systemUptime function, so I know the current time, and I don't depend the iOS system clock.

The problem is: Everytime that device is rebooted, or turned off, the systemUptime is reseted. Until here OK, I can solve it forcing the user to login again, and getting the server clock time again. My problem is to know when the device was rebooted. Can you help me? Thank you guys!

Comment: Can you clarify your goal?  Are you really interested in system uptime, or do you just want to make sure that your app uses times that are synchronized with your server's clock?

Comment: My goal is make the created files have the correct time, because in my case, users frequentilly put the iOS clock on the past, to try jump out our internet block. I need that the files have the time nearest the server time, because if the I need to control when the files will be sync and downloaded, I hope that I answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice would be to not refer to the device time at all.  Get the the files from the server and have the server also answer the server time that the files are retrieved.  You can store this in the file, in the file name, or separately on the device.

At some point in the future ask the server if there's a file newer than the server time you recorded earlier.

In this sense, the time isn't really a time at all, it's a version number, and you could make that explicit with the server too, using just an integer from the server that indicates progressing sequence of versions.

If it's important that your app be strong in this way, your only choice is to remain independent of device time.  Otherwise, there are too many ways it can break (including small time errors due to latency on the time check, or device factory resets or malicious actions by a user).  It's better to remain independent of device time if you can.

Comment: My big problem is: I have to iPads. First I have my account logged in the First iPad. So I created a draw, for example, sync it, and turn offline. Now I open this file and continue draw something. The first iPad stills offline. Now I loggin with the same account in the second iPad. I'll download the draw, and after the second iPad turns offline too. The same way I continue drawing this. If I have the correct time, I know which one will be the most recent that will be syncronized. But I now that it will be so hard, and now I am thinking in change our sync policy. Thank you dahn

Comment: Will you allow the two ipads to edit simultaneously? Then even with perfect time synch, the edits can collide.  So you will have to develop merge logic (for example, handle a case where one ipad edits an object that the other one deleted).  The alternative is to let one ipad "lock" the file while the other one edits.  Then you can still keep track of versions with a simple integer.

Comment: Thank you dahn, I'll align with my team here, and I talk with you after to say what happeneds. Thank for helping.

Answer (score 0):

When you get the systemUptime the first time, subtract it from the current (iOS) date and time.  That's the time the system was last brought up.

Then recalculate this value whenever necessary.  If the "time the system was last brought up" has changed, then you know it's time to log in again.

However, as suggested by another commenter, I suspect there's a better way to tackle this from scratch.

Comment: My problem is that I never can trust on device clock. This way I will be able to get the same problem that I have today. Thank you.